# Rails application redirects to root url whenever some large content is posted in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

I am running an application with Ruby 2.1 and Rails 4.1. Everything is working fine on `webrick` server and also `thin` server. But when i move it to `nginx` and `unicorn` server, the `post` request has some issue. Whenever i try to post some `large content` content in a form, the server redirects it to root `url`. It doesn't even reaches to its respective `controller`.

So I am guessing there is a problem with nginx as my code works perfectly fine on webrick or thin server. I checked my nginx settings and they are fine as same `app` is running on a different server perfectly fine with same settings. So its with that server. Its strange but I have no idea why this is happening.

In case somebody experienced same problem and have a fix please let me know. Thanks.

My server config

```
upstream cfd_sock {
  server unix:/home/harry/sites/cfd/tmp/unicorn.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80;

  root /home/harry/sites/cfd/public;

  server_name localhost;

  client_max_body_size 500m;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @app;
  }

  location @app {
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
    proxy_connect_timeout   360;
    proxy_pass http://cfd_sock;
 }
}
```

My Nginx conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 100M;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/sites/*;
}
```

Comment: Can you add your nginx config?

Comment: @YuryLebedev edited.

Comment: Can you try to change this to a capital `M`? `client_max_body_size 500M;`

Comment: @YuryLebedev no it doesnt work. Still the same.